# Strange space in border

Tags: html, css

```css
.cardboard-window {
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  resize: both;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 8px solid;
  border-image: url("https://sites.google.com/site/drawalbumimages/imgs/cardboard window.png");
  border-image-slice: 1 1 3 1 fill;
  border-width: 4px 4px 12px 4px;
  border-image-repeat: repeat;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute; margin:0; top:100%; transform:translateY(-150%);" class="cardboard-window">
  Window stuff...
</div>
```

Appearing a some very strange invisible space in `.cardboard-window` when i'm using a `transform:translate(...)`:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting a [border image](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/) you slice it to fit to your needs so i believe the spaces comes from the slicing action.
I couldn't find a way to fix that by modifying the border, but in your specific case you can just set a background-color of #c08f4f to your div.

If setting a background-color isn't good for you try this :

```css
.cardboard-window {
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  resize: both;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 8px solid;
  border-image: url("https://sites.google.com/site/drawalbumimages/imgs/cardboard window.png");
  border-image-slice: 1 1 3 1 fill;
  border-width: 4px 4px 12px 4px;
  border-image-repeat: repeat;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
 
.message-container{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-150%);
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-container">
  <div class="cardboard-window">
    Window stuff...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Griesur I have edited my answer and added another solution.